# get rid of tuple in list, erlang

Tags: filter, erlang

I want to get rid of all tuples in the list for eg.

I have something like this as an input

```
test:stack({push, [{{mul,{plus,{num,2},{num,3}},{num,4}},[]}]}, []). 
%% note:  (returns wrong output because of the multiple tuples brackets)
```

if i have something like this:

```
proj:stack({push, [mul,plus,{num,2},{num,3},{num,4}]}, []). 
%% this would return: 
%% [{push,{num,4}},{push,{num,3}},{push,{num,2}},
%%  {push,plus},{push,mul}] 
%% This is near to what I need.
```

my code is like this:

```
stack({push, []}, StackList) -> StackList;
stack({push,[H|T]}, StackList) ->   
stack({push, T}, [{push,H} | StackList]).
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
{push, {num, 4}}, {push, {num, 3}}, 
{push, {num, 2}}, {add}, {mul}, {pop}, {ret}
```

I thought of using filters to achieve this but maybe it is something else?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want a list with the initial value of each tuple or do you want to filter out any tuples inside the list?

Comment: `lists:map(fun({A}) -> A end, [{1},{2},{3}]).` does the trick, but this is of little consequence unless we know the actual problem you are trying to solve (unless its homework, in which case not doing this stuff by yourself is retarding your progress). What does your project do where this is something you need to do?

Comment: sry the idea was to remove the tuples brackets from [{1},{2},{3}] to get [1,2,3]

Comment: updated fully reuqirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too big for a comment. Meh...

This looks a lot like you are trying to build a stack machine, in this case maybe a calculator. There is a [good RPN example walkthrough in LYSE](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/functionally-solving-problems) that I strongly recommend you take a look at. It doesn't deal with this specific syntax, but it demonstrates how to accumulate a consumptive set of operations using matching in a function head.

Something you will have to decide is the semantics of your elements. Right now you have tuples of tuples of tuples -- and this is not what tuples are for. Tuples of the form `{Operation, Operand}` or `{Operation, Operand1, Operand2}` make perfect sense -- they are semantically distinct -- but tuples of the form `{OperationZ, {OperationX, Operand}, {OperationQ, Operand1, Operand2}}` don't make any sense, because each element of a tuple is supposed to have a distinct meaning. Here you have just nested a bunch of tuples which have their own meanings into a larger tuple which itself is now simply confused.

The solution is to use lists, not tuples. If you take this one step further, instead of using "push/pop" as operations of their own accord, consider unwrapping your tuples entirely, and treating every element of the list on its own terms *according to a rule set that underlies the system*. So instead of wrapping values in `{push, 4}` you just supply `4` because the implicit operation is always push (or pop, depending on your point of view... better, actually, to dispense with this concept, since the stack already exists as input).

To pull from your example above:

```
[{push,{num,4}},{push,{num,3}},{push,{num,2}},{push,plus},{push,mul}]
```

would become

```
[4, 3, 2, add, mul]
```

This can be interpreted with no ambiguity already, we don't need the confusion of the `push`, and `num` identifiers:

```
-module(rpn).
-export([calc/1]).

calc(List) ->
    [Res] = lists:foldl(fun calc/2, [], List),
    Res.

calc(mul, [N1, N2 | Stack]) -> [N1 * N2 | Stack];
calc(add, [N1, N2 | Stack]) -> [N1 + N2 | Stack];
calc(X, Stack) -> [X | Stack].
```

Hopefully this illustrates more than it confuses. Bear in mind that you *can* leave everything wrapped in tuples and match on the tuple tags and value variables, but this is not necessary. The above code had no typechecking at all, but if you add tags to the elements (but do *not* nest the tuples) then you can use those tags as a form of type-tagging (crashing immediately if you receive a wrong tag, or skipping any unexpected ones) -- but this means you need to back up one step further semantically:

```
[{num, 4}, {num, 3}, {num, 2}, {op, add}, {op, mul}]
```

Playing with this a bit just now winds up complicating the code to a degree that I'd really rather just use guards and crash early if the input is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code as you have it:

```
lists:filter(fun(E) -> E /= {} end, list1)
```

This will not filter all tuples out of a list. This only filters out list elements that are equal to the empty tuple {}. If you want a function that filters tuples out of a list, you should replace the E /= {} predicate in your lambda expression with a not and the is_tuple/1 BIF:

```
not is_tuple(E)
```

I am also a little confused by your initial question. You said

*list1= [{1},{2},{3}] I want it as list1 = [1,2,3]*

This makes me think you want to map over the list and transform each single element tuple in the list into its content. If this is your desired behavior, either use the map/2 BIF or a list comprehension.

```
[ E || {E} <- list1]
```

This expression is read as, "for each single element tuple in list1, generate a new list whose elements are the contents of those tuples."

Hope this helps. Enjoy Erlang.

Comment: sry they didnt work out for my code :s I will put in the full requirements